# Start external exe within own process

Tags: winapi, windows-7, vb6, executable, taskbar

I have a VB6 executable we use as a Starter executable for our real program.

The problem is that windows 7 shows a new icon in the taskbar for the new process, instead of the one i clicked on to start my program (of course, because the starter exe has already ended, and the new exe seems to be a new program).

Currently I use the Shell object to start the other exe. Is there a better way to do it from vb6, maybe by using a native C function with declare that does start an exe in the current process, without spawning a new process?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to **atzz** for the great information about Application Model IDs. I now have a shortcut to my app starter with a well defined id, and my app also sets the ID when started, and is now accesssible beautifully from the right icon in the toolbar. However, two problems persist:

1. The app is a Java App started with Exe4J, and I don't have any chance to set the AppID before Exe4J shows the splash screen, so while showing the splash screen there is a second icon in the taskbar.
2. If I don't manually drag my starter app icon from the Desktop to the toolbar, but instead use my apps icon and set it to be "sticky", the real app is sticked, and not the launcher.

Both problems would be beautifully solved if my launcher would start the app from within its own process. I heard something of using exec() instead of fork() for linux programs to achive this... is there something similar for windows?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to start a different executable in the current process. Why do you need to use a separate loader application written in VB 6? What problem does that solve?

Comment: The problem to check if there are updates available. If I check that from the main executable, I cannot overwrite it itself. Also, this ensures that a buggy main executable can always be updated.

Comment: You probably don't want to travel down the path of having a running process switch the actual executable code within it on a Windows machine. There are ways but any virus/malware scanner is going to go nuts (basically your problem perfectly describes how malicious code can try to spread). Stick with the launcher - it is a perfectly acceptable solution for the situation/goals you described.

Comment: I don't want to inject code, I just want to set the Application User Model ID of another process! There should be an API for that...

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is a way to accomplish what you need via Windows 7 taskbar API, though I never did it myself and thus don't remember clearly enough what I've read on the subject. Look around the *Application ID* concept.

Some links:

- [Developing for the Windows 7 Taskbar – Application ID](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/06/18/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.aspx)
- [Inside Windows 7 - Introducing The Taskbar APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx)

Comment: +1 Great answer, I believe when fiddeling with the app id I will be able to get what I want. Will post my solution when I am done.

Comment: @Daniel - wow, that was unexpected! not that i'm complaining, mind you :)

Comment: Better than dropping the points *g... If you don't want them just start a bounty and give them back to me ;)... just kidding.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the icon, why not give both programs the same icon (and the same App.Title). Then the user won't be able to tell the difference between the two taskbar entries. Presumably they aren't both visible at the same time.

Alternatively set your starter app not to appear in the taskbar (Form property ShowInTaskbar = False in the design view)

Comment: Yup, I agree. The second solution seems by far the simplest. Only disadvantage is that something doesn't show on the user's taskbar immediately after launching the app. I suppose you'd have to make the decision based on how much work the helper app is doing and how long it takes to load the real app.

Comment: The problem is, that usually, when there is a sticky shortcut on the taskbar, the running app shows as a button(?) border around the shortcut. If the app has its own exe and process, another icon pops up in the taskbar.

Comment: OK, so the problem is specific to the special Windows 7 taskbar. In that case go with [atzz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115018/start-external-exe-within-own-process/5115354#5115354)